# Bootstrapping and accessing session variables in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-session

Having problems accessing session variables through different actions in ZF.

Here are the contents of the bootstrapper:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initSession()
    {
            Zend_Session::start();
            $sessionUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUser');
    }

}
```

I assign a variable to $sessionUser in the IndexController:

```
                    $sessionUser->userId = $res->userId;
                    $sessionUser->organisationId = $res->organisation_organisationId;
                    $sessionUser->forename = $res->forename;
```

And attempt to access the variable in the Administrator controller:

```
$sessionUser->organisationId
```

Yet I receive the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: sessionUser in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/SA1/application/controllers/AdministratorController.php on line 17 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/SA1/application/controllers/AdministratorController.php on line 17
```

And ideas what could be causing this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the session variable back in your controller you also need to do:

```
$sessionUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUser');
```

Comment: Damn, you type faster than me. ;-)

Comment: Doh! I assumed having the variable defined in the Bootstrap would make it available to all the controllers. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error you are getting is obvious. The $sessionUser is not defined.

You must initialize such variable before assinging values to it. Put this in your controller:

```
 $sessionUser = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionUser');
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, got it sorted now by inserting the assignment into the controllers.